# LuaLaTeX does nothing at all

Tags: luatex, compiling

I installed TeX Live manually on Ubuntu 18.04 (using the script from http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/install-tl-unx.tar.gz). Now I want to use LuaLaTeX to compile documents like this one:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
        Hello world!
\end{document}
```

However, if I execute LuaLaTeX with this document using `lualatex main.tex`, there is no PDF file generated, but also no errors:

```
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.10.0 (TeX Live 2019) 
 restricted system commands enabled.
(./main.tex
LaTeX2e <2019-10-01> patch level 3
```

The only file generated is `main.log`:

```
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.10.0 (TeX Live 2019)  (format=lualatex 2020.1.9)  9 JAN 2020 11:55
 restricted system commands enabled.
**main.tex
(./main.tex
LaTeX2e <2019-10-01> patch level 3
Lua module: luaotfload-main 2019-11-10 3.11 luaotfload entry point
Lua module: luaotfload-init 2019-11-10 3.11 luaotfload submodule / initialization
Lua module: lualibs 2019-11-06 2.69 ConTeXt Lua standard libraries.
Lua module: lualibs-extended 2019-11-06 2.69 ConTeXt Lua libraries -- extended collection.
Lua module: luaotfload-log 2019-11-10 3.11 luaotfload submodule / logging
```

Compilation with pdfLaTeX or XeLaTeX works without any problems. Does anybody know what the problem might be?

Comment: Does the log-file really ends like this or is there more?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer That's all.

Comment: Hm. Did you install a full texlive?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yes, I did. Maybe I should try to install it again.

Comment: What happens if you run `luaotfload-tool  -u -vvv`?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer No output at all. If I use it with `sudo`, the output looks normal: https://pastebin.com/njnp1HkF. Actually, the same thing happens with `lualatex main.tex` - only works properly with `sudo`.

Comment: I don't have linux, but asked someone in the chat.

Comment: @FelixSchütz Probably luaotfload doesn't have the permission to create it's cache directory. What does `ls -ld ~ ~/.texlive2019`show?

Comment: @MarcelKrüger Looks good to me:
`ls: cannot access '/home/cfu2fe/.texlive2019': No such file or directory`
`drwxr-xr-x 22 cfu2fe cfu2fe 4096 Jan  9 16:53 /home/cfu2fe`

Comment: @FelixSchütz If you have `strace` installed, it would be interesting to see the last lines from `strace lualatex main.tex`. Otherwise you could try running `kpsewhich -expand-var '$TEXMFCACHE!$TEXMFVAR!$VARTEXMF'` Maybe LuaTeX got some paths mixed up

Comment: @MarcelKrüger last lines of `strace` output: https://pastebin.com/gVXqujXC. Output of `kpsewhich`: `/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-var:/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-var!/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-var!$VARTEXMF`.

Comment: @FelixSchütz The problem is that your TEXMFVAR is a system directory TeX isn't allowed to write to. Probably you changed the default during the TeXLive install. If there is no strong reason why you did this, you can probably fix the issue by deleting the line starting with `TEXMFVAR` from `/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf.cnf`.

Comment: @MarcelKrüger Oh I must have done that accidentally. Weird that lualatex doesn't produce an error. It works after removing the line - thank you very much for your help. Should I document that as an edit to the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`luaotfload` needs to store some caching related files which are normally stored in `$TEXMFVAR`, the directory reserved in TeX Live for generated data. For that, you need to give LuaTeX write access to this directory.

There are basically two reasons why this might not be the case:

- You have some very special setup where you are not allowed into your own home directory, so TeX can't create the default `TEXMFVAR` at `~/.texlive2019/texmf-var`.
- Or you changed the location of `TEXMFVAR` while installing TeX Live (or afterwards) and the new location isn't writable.

  You can see if your TEXMFVAR has been changed by looking at the file `texmf.cnf` in your TeX Live installation directory, e.g. `/usr/local/texlive/2019/`. If there is a line starting with `TEXMFVAR`, you have a customized `TEXMFVAR` and you have to ensure that this directory can be written to.

  If you don't have any good reason for changing the default, the easiest fix often is to restore the default setting by removing this line.